# Given a negative definite bilinear form on a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module, can we find a vector which induces a negative functional?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $V = \mathbb{Z}^n$ be a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module, and let $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denote a negative definite bilinear form. Let
$$V^+ := \{(v_1,\ldots,v_n)\in V : v_i > 0\}$$
Can we find a $v\in V$ such that for every $w\in V^+$, we have $(v,w) \le 0$?
Can we do better and even ensure $(v,w) < 0$?

In the particular case I'm interested in, let $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ denote the canonical basis of $V$, then the matrix of the bilinear form $(\cdot,\cdot)$ has negative entries on the diagonal, and is nonnegative everywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this turns out to have a trivial answer.

The key point is: Let $N$ be the matrix of the negative definite bilinear form $(\cdot,\cdot)$, then $N$ is invertible. Indeed, by definition all of its eigenvalues are negative, and so $\det(N) \ne 0$. Furthermore, for every non-zero vector $v\in V$, we have $(v,v) < 0$, and hence the form is nondegenerate, which implies that $N$ is in fact invertible.

Now, pick your favorite $z\in V$ such that all entries $z_i$ of $z$ are negative. Since $N$ is invertible, we can find $v\in V$ with $Nv = z$, which implies that if $e_i$ is the $i$th canonical basis vector, then $e_i^tNv = (e_i,v) = z_i < 0$ for every $i$, and thus for every $w\in V^+$, we have $(w,v) = (v,w) < 0$.